# Uncaught exception when using finite domain solver

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to do the unicorn problem from R&N's AI textbook in Prolog, but I get an uncaught exception immediately after calling my query (I know this from doing a trace).

```
magical:-
   forall(
      (  fd_domain_bool([Immortal, Mythical, Mammal, Horned, Magical]),
         fd_labeling([Immortal, Mythical, Mammal, Horned, Magical])
      ),
      (  (immortal#==>(mythical))
      ;  (#\mythical#==>(#\immortal#/\mammal))
      ;  (horned#==>immortal#\/mammal)
      ;  (magical#==>horned)
      )).
```

What's causing the exception? I've tried reformatting the arguments such that everything after the fd_domain_bool and fd_labeling are a single argument, this implementation which has every line as its own argument, and everything as one argument within the forall().

Comment: What exception do you get? If I add `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).`, I can load your code in SWI (without this, I get a syntax error because there are undefined operators), but then I get `Undefined procedure: fd_domain_bool/1`. Do you get the same? Please edit your question and tell us the exact error message you get.

Comment: You need to up-case all names like `immortal`....

Comment: @Isa: It's GNU.

Comment: Prolog names are case sensitive. And variables must begin with a capital letter or, if it's an anonymous variable, a `_`. Prolog sees `immortal` as an atom, and `immortal #==> (mythical)` attempts to execute `immortal` as a query which, of course, it cannot find.